# Ubuntu utility tool to know number threads and processes runnning in the OS

Tags: 16.04, server

Is there any GUI tool in ubuntu which helps in knowing the overall number of threads and processes running on the os itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ps -A` will show all processes, and `wc -l`can count them, so you can use

```
ps -A|wc -l
```

If you want to view the processes and sort them in different ways, `htop` is a good tool.

```
sudo apt-get install htop
```

Comment: thanx  :)  i  just have  one confusion  here

Comment: in  my  limits.conf  i have set  processes to be supported as

Comment: *     soft    nproc           127932
*     hard    nproc           127932

Comment: I don't understand. What is the confusion?

Comment: and  thread max is also set to the same value  but   when i   count  the  number of threads  it shows 32509  and then the  os shows that it cant create  thread  that is  sytem error  resource temporary  unavailable

Comment: that is  the confusion  if  the  thread count says  that  it  has  not reached the  threshold  limit  then  y the os cant  create threads?

Comment: You have very many threads? I had 188 processes running, when I tested, and `htop` showed the following tasks near the top right corner: `Tasks: 87, 220 thr, 99 kthr; 1 running`

Comment: @kushalbhattacharya Your comments will be easier to read if you only press ENTER after you have finished your thought.  The command input box works differently from most message boxes like the questions and answer boxes on this forum, or the regular message boxes on regular forums.  You might try **periods** rather than **ENTERs** between thoughts.

Comment: yes   when i ran  this command  i got  32509  threads  and i have  127593 value  being  set as  threads-max

Comment: @L.D.James  i am really sorry mate  :)  this wont happen again

Comment: I don't know the details, but maybe there is some other limit for the maximum number of threads, for example a power of 2. Your number `32509` is near `2^15=32768`. (I'm guessing here.) Let us hope that someone, who really knows the maximum number of processes or threads will see your question and comments and reply.

Comment: @kushalbhattacharya No problem... just a friendly tip for a new user.  Enjoy the system!

Comment: So :)  do I post it as new thread  about  this  question  that  i  have @sudodus

Comment: That is a good idea. The main problem should be in the title, and it helps a lot with a detailed description in the main text of the question.

Comment: ok thanks  for  helping  me  out mate  :) i am posting it as  a  new question  here

Comment: You are welcome, and good luck, @kushalbhattacharya :-)

Comment: hey i have used  a different command  now  to tally  the value ,the command i have used is  
ps -eo nlwp | tail -n +2 | awk '{ num_threads += $1 } END { print num_threads }'


but this gives  a  different  value  than  the normal  one is there any  difference  between the  two  :)?

Comment: Yes, you get the number of threads in each process with `-o nlwp`, ( -e and -A are equivalent). So I think your command is calculating the number of threads correctly, while my simple answer calculates the number of processes. (But I have never learned how to use `awk`, I used another way to check the result.)